# Errors after upgrading the spring version to 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I upgraded the application from spring boot version 2.6.7 to 2.7.0 and started getting below errors which caused the failure of all test cases.

```
Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrappe
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException at DefaultLifecycleProcessor
```

I do have below dependencies in my build.gradle file :

```
implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.9'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.7.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.7.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.1-jre'
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13', version: '3.1.0'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your post.

Comment: By the way, `kafka_2.13` is the server dependency, not the client or test package. You might want to look at using `spring-kafka` dependency